FreeRDP Black Screen
I'm experiencing difficulty trying to use FreeRDP.
I have Debian 12 (Bookworm) running on my 10.0.0.93 server at home. I did "sudo apt-get install freerdp2-x11" and "sudo apt-get install freerdp2-shadow-x11".
Then I started the RDP server with "sudo freerdp-shadow-cli /bind-address:10.0.0.93 /sec:rdp /may-view /may-interact -auth". It responded "Listening on [10.0.0.93]:3389".
Then I went to my Windows 11 desktop (in the same room, at 10.0.0.100), started Windows' RDP and connected to "10.0.0.93:3389". It connected right away, but the screen was (and remained) entirely black.
Back on my Debian machine, the terminal was continuously reporting "[ERROR][com.freerdp.server.shadow.x11] - X11 error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) Error code: 8, request code: 49, minor code: 0" over and over.

akallabeth at the FreeRDP github site said to just use:
gnome-remote-desktop
Worked perfectly!
